# Stencil keydown event listener is not working when it is in an NPM package

Tags: javascript, frontend, stenciljs, stencil-component

I am using Stencil2+ in my application. I have one query related to the keydown event of Stencil. When I use the keydown event directly from the component, the listener is able to react to the event. But when I am using my component inside another component as an NPM package, the listener is not able to react on the event. I have tried to use the target option as document, but the document option is targeting the document of my main application not the NPM package application.

```js
@Listen('keydown', { passive: true })
private keyListener(ev: KeyboardEvent) {
   if (ev.key === 'Escape') {
     this.hide()
   }
}
```

Let me know if anybody has faced this issue in their application and if anybody have any solution for it.

Comment: Could you share more details as to what component are you trying to build. And also where are you using this component like React, Vue or Angular

Comment: Hello @PratikWadekar, I am using the stencil component in an stencil application as npm package. The npm package component is containing keydown listner.

Comment: Have you created this stencil component on your own? Or using a third party library or something?

Comment: yes, both components are created by me.

Comment: Could you share the code where you are trying to use this component?

Comment: @PratikWadekar, do you face this issue in. your code anytime?. i saw one solution on git issue, regarding using target as 'document'. I tried this, https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1527. But this document is getting considered for whole application not for npm package application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246734/discussion-between-priya-and-pratik-wadekar).